# How to design a reactive stream actor system with fan out capability

Tags: reactive-programming, actor, akka-stream, akka-cluster, backpressure

I am trying to implement an actor-based system with back-pressure capability. As a requirement, the master process receives streaming data in JSON format. Each JSON event however has several fields such as {ip: '123.43.12.1', country: 'US', ... etc}. The structure of JSON is known beforehand.

Now, I have to somehow flatten the JSON structure into (key, value) pair. For example, the above data can be flattened into (ip, freq), (country, freq) where freq is the number of time an ip (such as '123.43.12.1') appears in the data stream.

A very natural way is to forward each (key, value) pair to corresponding child/remote actor for further evaluation. For example, ('123.43.12.1', 1) is sent to IP-Actor; ('US', 1) is sent to Country-Actor and so on.

I want to make sure the whole system is back pressure. Thing is more complicated in this case because an event {ip: '123.43.12.1', country: 'US'} is only considered as processed if both IP-Actor and Country-Actor has finished processing flattened-out pair ('123.43.12.1', 1), ('US', 1). Each actor might have different processing speed (for instance, IP-Actor is much faster than Country-Actor). In that case, I want the master process which received stream will wait/block until there are demand signal (happen when both actors finished processing existing data in its mailbox). Otherwise, some actor might full of message in mailbox (Country-Actor - slow one) but message still coming in because other actor mailbox is empty (IP-Actor - faster one).

Could anyone please suggest if reactive-stream specs provides such functionality. If not, is there anyway to achieve the functionalities in the most efficient way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The type of synchronization between Actors that you described is exactly what you want to avoid in the Actor Model.  Any "wait/block" is antithetical to reactive programming.  I suggest using a single stream `Flow` to do the updating.

You first need to process the json data:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

//your original source of json strings
val jsonSrc : Source[String, NotUsed] = ???

case class JsonObject(ip : String, country : String)

//use your favorite json parser
def jsonParser(jsonStr : String) : JsonObject = ???

val parserFlow = Flow[String] map jsonParser
```

Next define the counter logic and use `Flow.scan` to generate counters with incrementing values:

```
type IPCounter = Map[String,Int]
val emptyIPCounter = Map.empty[String,Int] withDefaultValue 0

type CountryCounter = Map[String, Int]
val emptyCountryCounter = Map.empty[String,Int] withDefaultValue 0

type Counters = Tuple2[IPCounter, CountryCounter]
val emptyCounters = (emptyIPCounter, emptyCountryCounter)

def updateCounters(counters : Counters, jsonObj : JsonObject) : Counters = {
  (counters._1.updated(jsonObj.ip, counters._1(jsonObj.ip) + 1),
   counters._2.updated(jsonObj.country, counters._2(jsonObj.country) + 1))
}

val counterFlow = Flow[JsonObject].scan(emptyCounters)(updateCounters)
```

Finally, combine everything together:

```
val counterSource : Source[Counters, NotUsed] = jsonSrc via parserFlow via counterFlow
```

The result is exactly what you asked for: a backpressured stream that only forwards on counter values when all of the counters have been updated.